# Finding specified number of predictors using stepwise regression

Tags: r, matlab, regression

I am trying to find limited number of predictors (max=6) among 104 variables. So, I am using stepwise regression (for each variable I have 10532 values). I tried MATLAB:

```
mdl = stepwiselm(Pr, obs,'PEnter', 0.06)
```

However, it gave me about 70 variable. 
Also, I tried to solve the problem using R package `leaps`:

```
b <- leaps::regsubsets(obs ~ ., data=Pr, nbest=1, nvmax=6)
```

I get the error below:

> "Error in leaps.exhaustive(a, really.big) : 
>   Exhaustive search will be S L O W, must specify really.big=T"

I know it should be an easy way to solve this problem, but I cannot seem to figure out the proper formatting.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
leaps::regsubsets(obs ~ ., data=Pr, nbest=1, nvmax=6, really.big=T)
```

or you can try

```
library(MASS)
# Fit the full model 
full.model <- lm(obs ~ ., data=Pr)
# Stepwise regression model
step.model <- stepAIC(full.model, direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE)
summary(step.model)
```